# Sharepoint Sharing configuration not available/missing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, share

In our SharePoint 2013 on-premises site permissions settings, if I click on `Access Request Settings`  I can see only one check box with email configuration.

I am not able to configure sharing options, as they are not available.

How can I enable these options. as referred [here](http://www.sharepointusecases.com/2014/11/managing-sharing-access-requests-sharepoint-site/)

Or is this available only in Office 365?